# About languages that allow calling C functions directly

Tags: c, julia

I stumbled into [Julia](http://julialang.org/) (programming language) and got specially interested with it's ability [to call C functions without any wrapper](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/manual/calling-c-and-fortran-code/). In fact it looks more like an instant C wrapper:

```
 path = ccall( (:getenv, "libc"), Ptr{Uint8}, (Ptr{Uint8},), "SHELL")

 time = ccall( (:clock, "libc"), Int32, ())
```

So I've got a few questions:

1. Is there any drawback on using this feature over having a formal wrapping API?
2. When this kind of feature **should not** be used?

PS: Would be nice to have other languages capable of doing the same thing, as easily, listed.

Comment: It looks like you are making a wrapper on the fly with those instructions.  Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: All three questions (each of which would probably deserve their own post) are pretty open-ended. I'm tempted to vote to close this as *too broad*...

Comment: I could make the question less broad, but not sure which part is more important. For example, knowing other languages that have same feature is useful to me but knowing about possible drawbacks is very important too.

Comment: @marcioAlmada: that may be so, but because something would be useful to you doesn't mean it's not too broad by house standards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the languages provide trivial interop with C. In statically typed languages it is required to declare imported function signature ([Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/FFI_Introduction), [C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)) for obvious reasons.

In dynamically typed languages it is not required. For instance see how it is done [python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) or [lua](http://luajit.org/ext_ffi_tutorial.html). Nothing wrong here, this is just a feature of dynamic typization.

Of course if you want to target your library to a given language it is better to write and document bindings in terms of language so users won't have to deal with C interop themselves. It is obviously just more convinient. But wrappers themself can internally use this kind of FFI that's just a feature you get from the language.